# Creating new folder while installing javafx application in desktop

Tags: javafx, netbeans

I have a javafx application and i have built it using netbeans. I am able to create a desktop shortcut for the application. But what i need is a new empty folder on the desktop while installing the application. Is it possible?

I have tried adding mkdir dir=${user.home}/Desktop/new folder in the post-deploy tag of build file but it creates the folder before installing the application.

Comment: please provide more detail about how are you installing the application, are you using maven or graddle we need more detail to help you

Comment: i am not using maven or gradle i used only javafx and created a installer using netbeans ide. The application works fine but i need to add a folder in the desktop while installing the application.

Comment: [take a look may be this will help you](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BD5w5oLbnVI)

Comment: I can create application shortcut, but i am not able to create a new folder in the desktop.

Comment: have you found a solution ?

Comment: No @MohammedHousseynTaleb